# fast session connect using http prebind in openfire

Tags: php, xmpp, openfire, strophe

i am implementing openfire chat in crossplatform app for mobile device ,  mobile has a weaker connectivity so i am trying to use http-prebind with openfire using
[XMPP BOSH using PHP](https://github.com/Marko-M/XMPP-BOSH-toolkit) to get session details so that i can attach to existing connection using [strophe](http://strophe.im/strophejs/doc/1.2.3/files/strophe-js.html).

now the hurdle is when i run example of `XMPP BOSH Tollkit` to get session info

**i am getting following error in web browser**

[image]

**and following error in openfire**

[image]

i have installed [openfire connection manager](https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/connection_manager.jsp)  too and thought prebind might work with it but no luck.

have read few articles related to http-prebind but i never get it working , i have tried this long back but i failed at that time too

article

[prebind sessions](http://metajack.im/2009/12/14/fastest-xmpp-sessions-with-http-prebinding/)

[Http pre-bind](http://metajack.im/2008/10/03/getting-attached-to-strophe/)